# Generalize $r\cos(\theta n)$ Into Polynomials in Terms of x

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I understand that it is possible to generalize $\cos(\theta n)$ via Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind, and I was also wondering if it is possible to generalize $r\cos(\theta n)$ in a similar fashion. For instance:

$\ P_1(x) = r\cos (\ 1 \theta) = x$

$\ P_2(x) = r\cos (\ 2 \theta) = 2r\cos^2 \theta - r =$ Junk in terms of x

$\ldots$

Ad infinitum for all positive whole number values of n. Specifically, I am looking for a series that generates these polynomials.

Comment: As you have shown yourself $P_2(x) = \frac{2x^2}{r} - r$ cannot be written solely as a function of $x$. You need two parameters specifying it so it should read $P_n(x,r)$. You can use the original Chebychef polynomials: $r\cos(n\theta) = r T_n(x/r)$ where $x = r\cos(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Even $P_2$ cannot be written in terms of $x$. More generally, it is very unlikely that a bunch of expressions of two variables (in this case $r, \theta$) could be simultaneously reduced to expression of one variable (in this case $x$) by a substitution, unless the two variables always appear together in the same form.

Just to be sure, to prove it isn't possible, note that if $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $x = r \cos \theta$ is equal to $0$ for any $r$.
Thus any expression of $x$ must be constant along these values of $(r,\theta)$.
However, when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$,
$$
P_2 = r \cos(2\theta) = r \cos (\pi) =  -r
$$
is not constant for all $r$.
Thus $P_2$ cannot be written as an expression in $x$.

---

In order to express $r \cos (n \theta)$ as a polynomial, it would be far more promising to select *two* variables, and attempt to write it as a polynomial in those. The obvious pair of variables is $(r, \cos \theta)$. However, you could try other pairs of variables and see if what you get is a polynomial.
You just need to be able to recover $r$ and $\cos \theta$ from the two variables together.